# Hibernate Example queries

Tags: java, hibernate

I will explain the problem with an example.
I have a Vehicle object which has a model name and a make. When the make is given, relevant vehicle should be listed. when both make and model is given,then suitable vehicles should be listed.

For example: 
There is an entity called 'Vehicle' .It has a proxy called makeModel whose Entity name is `MakeModel` . MakeModel has proxies which are 'make' and 'model' whose entity names are Model and Make.Both Entititiyes 'Model' and 'Make'  have String variable 'name'.Here are classes

```
class Vehicle{
 private Integer vehicleId;  
 private MakeModel makeMOdel;
 //getters and setters  
}

class MakeModel {
 private Make make;
 private Model model;  
 //getters and setters  
}  

class Make{
 private Integer mid;
 private String make;
}  
class Model{  
 private Integer mdlid;
 private String modelName;
}
```

Here is how I tried to get vehicle list. Here, `session` is Hibernate Session.

```
Criteria cr= session.createCriteria(Vehicle.class);  

MakeModel mkmd=new MakeModel();  
if( /* if only the make is give */){  
 Make mk=new Make();  
 mk.setMake("Toyota");  
 mkmd.setMake(mk);
}  
else if(if both make and and model given){  
 Make mk=new Make();  
 mk.setMake("Toyota");  
 mkmd.setMake(mk);  
 Model md=new Model("Venus");  
 mkmd.setModel(md);
 }  

cr.createCriteria("makeModel").add(Example.create(mkmd));List l=cr.list();
```

*But this returns all vehicles*.
I want to get all vehicles using hibernate criteria not HQL.

A same question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482864/hibernate-criteria-upon-associated-objects/7483057#7483057) and referred [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) also.  Any one let me know where is wrong and how to retrieve vehicle list according to given criteria.

Comment: And the question is? The answer you referenced provides a good starting point. What did you try? And what does 'I couldn't solve the problem' really mean?

Comment: Obtaining a proper hibernate criteria for this is not that hard, but it would be a lot easier if you could provide the code for the Vehicle and MakeModel entities.

Comment: @Home. Thanks for your attention and question was edited with all codes.

Comment: From the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-examples: *Version properties, identifiers and associations are ignored*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that you are passing to your function *makeValue* and *modelValue*, which are the make and the model you want, you would have:

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Vehicle.class);  // Create the criteria on desired class
cr.createAlis("makeModel", "makeModel")
  .createAlias("makeModel.make", "make")
  .createAlias("makeModel.model", "model");  // Creating aliases makes a join on those tables 
if (makeValue != null){
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("make.make", makeValue))  // If you have a makeValue passed, filter by it
}
if (makeModel != null){
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("model.modelName", modelValue));  // If you have a makeModel passed, filter by it
}

return cr.list();    // Return the list
```

The result will be a `List<Vehicle>`. You can add a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to your method to avoid seeing unchecked cast warnings.

Comment: The Criteria was returning a list of Vehicle. I've just written the last comment wrong.

Comment: It gave me long exeption stacktraces. :( . I m not an expert and not clear this point of your code `cr.createAlias("makeModel", "makeModel")
  .createAlias("make", "make")` setting alias 'makeModel is ok, but 'make' .. because there is not make in Vehicle only the MakeModel has.

Comment: But still an exception is thrown. `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: make of: EntityCls.Vehicle` Then I tried ` cr.add(Restrictions.eq("makeModel.make",makeValue));` directly no alias. but another exception is thrown `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: makeModel.make of: EntityCls.Vehicle`

Comment: I have made yet again some changes. I got confused with your choice of names for `make`. You have the Class make and the field make. You should use something like you used for class `Model`, field `modelName`. See my edited post, and maybe try with a `makeName` field in the `Make class`.

Comment: PERFECT !!! Thank you very much. It worked. and I learned more from this too. :)   but one more thing. can't we do the same thing using `Hibernate.Example`?

Comment: I cannot answer to that, as I do not know much about hibernate's Example. Glad it worked out for you.